# Explanation and resolution of [intersection?] conflict in third-party module?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm getting this error trying to put a `direction` property on an `Animatable.View` from `react-native-animatable`:

```
Type '{ children: Element; animation: string; iterationCount: "infinite"; direction: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<AnimatableProperties<ViewStyle> & ViewPr...'.
  Type '{ children: Element; animation: string; iterationCount: "infinite"; direction: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<AnimatableProperties<ViewStyle> & ViewProps>'.
    Types of property 'direction' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

**Tracing through the type declarations I can't seem to find the cause of this issue - `direction` appears to be unambiguously defined on `AnimatableComponent` via `AnimatableProperties`? Also, whatever the issue is, how can I resolve it to at least remove the noise of the error output? Also, I don't suppose there's a way to like "print debug" the types by having the compiler output what *it* considers the final `AnimatableProperties` interface?**

**There *is* a `direction` property on the `ViewStyle` type, but as far as I can tell that shouldn't be relevant.**

**I believe I extracted the relevant typings below:**

```
// https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable/blob/master/typings/react-native-animatable.d.ts

import {
  ...
  ViewProperties,
  ViewStyle,
  ...
} from 'react-native';

interface AnimatableProperties<S extends {}>
{
  ...
  direction?: 'normal' | 'reverse' | 'alternate' | 'alternate-reverse';
  ...
}

interface AnimatableComponent<P extends {},S extends {}> extends
  NativeMethodsMixin,
  AnimatableAnimationMethods,
  ClassicComponentClass<AnimatableProperties<S> & P>
{
  ...
}

export const View : AnimatableComponent<ViewProperties,ViewStyle>;
export type View = AnimatableComponent<ViewProperties,ViewStyle>;
```

```
// https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-native/legacy-properties.d.ts

import {
  ...
  ViewProps,
  ...
} from "react-native";

declare module "react-native" {
  ...
  export type ViewProperties = ViewProps;
  ...
}
```

```
// https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/View/ViewPropTypes.js

export type ViewProps = {
  // there's no direction property here or [seemingly] on TVViewProps
} & TVViewProps;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out where the conflict comes from - `ViewProps` is actually defined as:

```
// https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-native/index.d.ts

export interface FlexStyle
{
  ...
  direction?: "inherit" | "ltr" | "rtl";
  ...
}

export interface LayoutProps extends FlexStyle {}

export interface ViewProps
  extends ViewPropsAndroid, ViewPropsIOS, GestureResponderHandlers, Touchable, AccessibilityProps, LayoutProps
{
  ...
}
```

So `FlexStyle` is directly in the properties rather than the style.